# Interacting with erc20 using web3js

Tags: web3js, erc-20, json-rpc

I am trying to fetch the balance for a wallet with address WALLET_ADDRESS, in an ERC20 contract located at CONTRACT_ADDRESS with the following approach:

```
let contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);

var balance = await contractInstance.methods.balanceOf(WALLET_ADDRESS).call();
```

The resulting input was:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Can you share the `CONTRACT_ADDRESS` that you use?

Comment: Actually looking at the web3js source it would be more interesting what rpc endpoint you use. It seems your connected rpc is not returning any data.

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/5d027191c5cb7ffbcd44083528bdab19b4e14744/packages/web3-providers-http/src/index.js#L107

Comment: `CONTRACT_ADDRESS` is "0x4da27a545c0c5B758a6BA100e3a049001de870f5".

Comment: @ehatin17 The code seems fine, possible error are: 1/ the address is wrong, 2/ the abi is wrong, 3/ connected to the wrong network, 4/ network issues. How do you connect to the blockchain? Infura, own node, ganache,..